# Onde está o erro no replace js?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
t = "(10px,10px)"
t = t.replace(/-|\d+/g,3,5)
```

Queria que resultasse em (3px,5px)

Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [@dvd ja explicou o motivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277567/14213).

> O replace só aceita 2 parâmetros:
>
> `replace(string_buscada, nova_string);`

Minha contribuição é no método de fazer isso, que seria usando um *callback* no lugar do *replace*, assim :

```js
var t = "(10px,10px)"
var change = [3,5];
var def = 10;
t = t.replace(/-|\d+/g,function(m){
  return change.length?change.shift():def;
});

console.log(t);
```

#### Explicação

O *callback* vai alterar a captura encontrada pelo valor passado no `return`, como estou passando o `shift` da `var change` vai retirar o primeira valor da mesma e retorna para substituição e assim por diante para cada *match* encontrado.

A `var def` é para caso `change` fique vazia e ainda tenha `matchs` a serem substituídos.

#### Obs

A regex para números negativos esta de fato errada. Sugiro usar :

```
/[+-]?\d+/g
```

Comment: Quem sabe sabe :D +1 ... callback!

Comment: vlw, @GuilhermeNascimento :D

Comment: caraca vey, que incrível

Comment: Fiquei impressionado...
Quem sabe sabe...
Agradeço realmente a todos.

Answer (score 4):

O `replace` só aceita 2 parâmetros:

```
replace(string_buscada, nova_string);
```

Logo seu código não irá funcionar desta forma. Uma sugestão é usar `match` e fazer 2 `replaces` com os índices do resultado da regex:

```js
t = "(10px,10px)";
//    ↑↑   ↑↑
//   m[0] m[1]

m = t.match(/[-|\d]+/g);
t = t.replace(m[0],3).replace(m[1],5);
console.log(t);
```

Outro exemplo com valores diferentes:

```js
t = "(4px,2px)";
m = t.match(/[-|\d]+/g);
t = t.replace(m[0],3).replace(m[1],5);
console.log(t);
```

### Edit

Conforme levantando pelo amigo **[wmsouza](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/60376/wmsouza)**, essa regex não está correta. Caso um dos números fosse negativo, iria fazer a substituição apenas do sinal negativo e não do número todo.

A regex correta seria:

> `/[-|\d]+/g`

Exemplo:

```js
t = "(4px,-2px)";
m = t.match(/[-|\d]+/g);
t = t.replace(m[0],3).replace(m[1],5);
console.log(t);
```

Comment: Uma duvida.. tem necessidade de `-|` ? https://regexr.com/3l34j

Comment: Tem se o número for negativo e queira mudar pra positivo.

Comment: Mas veja, estive testando [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/huxoxaz/1/edit?js,console), deixando número negativo `"(4px,-2px)"` ao executar o retorno é `"(3px,52px)"`, que loucura é essa? rs

Comment: Verdade. Esse regex tah bugado. Eu nem entrei no mérito da regex porque foi o cara que colocou na pergunta. Mas foi bom vc ter percebido isso para acrescentar uma sugestão na resposta.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta

Answer (score 1):

### O [`Replace`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) tem apenas 2 argumentos.

O segundo argumento do `Replace` não é tipo *array* de parâmetros. No `Replace` você deve colocar uma expressão que representa a substituição de todos as partes da expressão regular no segundo argumento. Você configura os grupos que quer capturar na sua expressão regular e utiliza a expressão `$n` onde `n` é o número do grupo capturado.

Exemplo abaixo:

```js
var t = "(10px,10px)";
var n = ["3", "5"];
var r = t.replace(/(\()\d+(px,)\d+(px\))/g, "$1"+n[0]+"$2"+n[1]+"$3");

console.log(t);
console.log(r);
```